# How to get the size of an on demand backup in Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm taking daily on demand backup of my cloud SQL instance in GCP. It's a PostgreSQL 9.6 instance.

I would like to know the size (in GB or MB) of each backup. How can I get this information using gcloud CLI or the console (web UI)?

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible at this moment. There is already a [Feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120511156) in that regards, please star it. Another [one](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78433287).

Also official documentation states the following [about backup size](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/backups?_ga=2.101679361.-1248134499.1625751800#about_backup_size):

> Cloud SQL backups are incremental. They contain only data that changed
> after the previous backup was taken. Your oldest backup is a similar
> size to your database, but the sizes of subsequent backups depend on
> the rate of change of your data. When the oldest backup is deleted,
> the size of the next oldest backup increases so that a full backup
> still exists.

I have also tried gcloud sql backups describe [ID] --instance=[instancename] and that does not give us the required information.

Comment: Thank you, just put another star on that issue. I'll wait to see if someone else can offer a work around to this problem.